# How to programmatically deselect the currently selected row in a JTable (swing)?

Tags: java, swing

I want to programmatically deselect the currently selected row (or rows) in a JTable.

Basically I want the opposite of this:

```
JTable table = ...;
table.setRowSelectionInterval(x,x);
```

I tried (with little hope) using:

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(-1,-1)
```

or

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(1,0)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is a method on `JTable` called `clearSelection`. This, in turn calls `clearSelection` on the `ListSelectionModel` of the table and the column model.

Comment: Duh! For some reason, I assumed the method would be a setter, so I only searched for methods starting with "set". Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

I believe you can use this:

```
table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection().
```

The SelectionModel is what actually handles the selection. JTable just has a few shortcuts.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks