# java swing - deselect a selected row in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an instance of `JTable` in my java swing application. I want to deselect a selected row from this table. From [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019685/1531130), `JTable` has provided `clearSelection()` method that deselect **all** selected rows in the table. But I want to deselect **one** row. How can I do this?

Comment: programatically (some event) or by event from Mouse/KeyEvent (CTRL is implemented in API)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ListSelectionModel.removeSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)?
```

Comment: Please add some explanation how this answer help OP in fixing posted issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.jroller.com/ethdsy/entry/jtable_selection_toggle) it toggles the selection of a row in jtable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that:

```
        JTable table = new JTable(); // your table instance
        TableModel dataModel = new DefaultTableModel(); // table model
        DefaultListSelectionModel selectionModel = new DefaultListSelectionModel(); //table selection model
        table.setModel(dataModel);      
        table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
        int desiredRow = 0; // row which you want to deselect
        selectionModel.removeSelectionInterval(desiredRow, desiredRow); // Removing selection for desired row
```